# Unable to get the value of text field in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is simple even though i don't know why i don't get it to work.
I just need the value of the text field. Here is the code. http://jsfiddle.net/VL8hr/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var firstname = $('.firstname').val();
   alert(firstname);

});
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong. it should be $('#firstname').val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selector is wrong. You have used id attribute, but in your javascript code you tends to use it as a class.
It should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
   alert(firstname);

});
```

you can differentiate between id and class selector over here.

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) instead of [class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) since `firstname` is the `id` of the element

```
var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9Stwa/)

Answer (score 1):

`#` is selector for `id` and `.` is selector for `class`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
       alert(firstname);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
   alert(firstname);

});
```